# How can i use django's runscript?

Tags: django

I am trying to run a script using django's runscript. I followed everything in the documentation. Did i miss something?

[image: Here is the files that i created]

But when i tried running it from the command line. it says unknown command 'runscript'

(env) C:\Users\MIS\hr system\hr_project>python manage.py runscript automail.py
Unknown command: 'runscript'

Comment: Why use runscript when you can make own custom management commands in django?

Comment: In my case, I hadn't set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io) if you want the `runscript` command. If you don't want to do that, you can:

- Run your script directly. Keep in mind that you need to specify the Django settings module as such:

```py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "your_project_name.settings")

from your_project.models import SomeModel

# Your code goes here...
```

- Make a custom `manage.py` command. You can use the official how-to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: yea didn't install the django-extensions. Thanks for the additional answer